# python pandas read_excel how to leave date as str without parsing

Tags: excel, pandas

hi I have an excel with date format of dd/mm/yyyy, and datatype = `general`

[image]

I read some post and tried

```
df = pd.read_excel(f_in 
               ,converters={'Created Date': str}
               ,engine='openpyxl')
```

and

```
df = pd.read_excel(f_in 
                   ,dtype={'Created Date': str}
                   ,engine='openpyxl')
```

both got same wrong result:

```
for ee in df['Created Date'][0:3]:
    print(ee, type(ee), '\n')

2019-04-11 00:00:00 <class 'str'>   ##this was parsed as mm/dd/yyyy and coerced into str, not left as is

18/11/2019 <class 'str'> 

25/11/2019 <class 'str'>
```

---

update: tried `parse_dates=False` and still not work:

```
df = pd.read_excel(f_in
                   ,parse_dates=False
                   ,engine='openpyxl')

for ee in df['Created Date'][0:3]:
    print(ee, type(ee), '\n')

2019-04-11 00:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'> 

18/11/2019 <class 'str'> 

25/11/2019 <class 'str'>
```

---

update SOLVED: thanks to @cottontail

In excel, the first cell in this column is actually `Date` type, when I make the whole column `general` type, it became

[image]

it looks like this when read into python

```
df = pd.read_excel(f_in
                   ,parse_dates=False
                   ,engine='openpyxl')

for ee in df['Created Date'][0:3]:
    print(ee, type(ee), '\n')

43566 <class 'int'> 

18/11/2019 <class 'str'> 

25/11/2019 <class 'str'>
```

then I can convert to `datetime` based on the type, or based on whether it contains `\`

Comment: I think you need to read in as dates and then reformat it.

Comment: pd.read_excel(parse_dates=False, path=D://xxxxxxx)
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: thanks @CharlieBONS! I tried it and it doesn't work for - see update is OP pls. thank u!

Comment: Are you sure the first value: `4/11/2019` is of type=general? If `4/11/2019` was created on an Excel sheet, it will be automatically read in as date. You can read in the sheet normally and then reformat is later using `dt.strftime`.

Comment: @cottontail thanks a lot! Excel type is the problem - the first cell is of Date type